# Read and extract parameters from a file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am writing a parser that takes a text file and returns an object. The file looks like this:

```
Val1 3 x 1 - i
0 t
has
Val2 2 r hgs * i
0 t
```

Now the information comes in groups of lines. First, the first 3 lines, second, the next 2 lines. This I'd be able to tell how many lines the group has from some data (say numbers **2**, **3** in the first line of each group).

The result would be:

```
result = {Val1:{p1:v1, p2:v2}, Val2:{...}}
```

Where none of the `Val<X>` keys would be repeated in the source file.

I've written a simple code that would do this, this is just the basic scheme:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(path); //array buffer
const arr = file.toString('utf8').split('\n')
```

And then I iterate over the array.

Now this program will send information from server back the client browser so it should run reasonably fast.

Is this a fast technique that you'd use? Or is there some other built-in way that would be faster?

Comment: Is it currently too slow for you? Or why are you asking? Without know what you actually do, how can we judge whether it's fast or not?

Comment: @FelixKling it is just that I may not be aware of a better way to convert it, as I am not an expert in Node. If I guide myself by how it runs, it seems ok (not too slow at least). Thanks for opening my eyes on that.

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, you could experiment with not loading the whole file into memory at once, but only read the parts that you need to process the next value. You could also experiment with streaming the individual values back to the client, instead of waiting to build a complete object. Whether or not that will actually make a difference for your application is something you'll have to measure. It might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Is your parse open source? I kind of need such a parse to extract text from files like pdf and image.